# Ubuntu on Dragon Touch

Tags: system-installation

I've just been given a Dragon Touch A1X tablet as a delayed Christmas present. Would it be possible to install Ubuntu on that since it is running 4.4.2?

I spent 30 years as a Unix guru, so I'm not afraid of the command line in any way.

Cheers,

David

---

The tablet is running Android 4.4.2 which, in my ignorance, I thought was one of the newest version. Am I wrong, and does it make any difference to my question?

Comment: Are you trying to install *Ubuntu* or Ubuntu touch?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) is a list of devices on which Ubuntu Touch is tested and (kinda) known to work. <sup>Touch works great on my Nexus 4.</sup> The chances of Ubuntu Touch running on a phone or ARM device not in that list by pure coincidence is functionally infintesimal.

Unfortunately, the Dragon is not on there.

I don't know if you want to install Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Touch (wildly separate), but I know from experience that if you're like me and you're willing to sacrifice the usability of your device for pure awesome, you can follow [this guide](http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian) on how to put *Debian* on a tablet.

Yes, Debian, not Ubuntu, because suffice it to say Ubuntu is bloated, and Ubuntu *is* Debian, just with a buncha different stuff installed, and a lot of Ubuntu just won't work on ARM where Debian will. Same package manager, same distro. <sup>just kidding</sup>